# Why is saving state_dict getting slower as training progresses?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm saving my model's and optimizer's state dict as follows:

```
if epoch % 50000 == 0:
  #checkpoint save every 50000 epochs
  print('\nSaving model... Loss is: ', loss)
  torch.save({
      'epoch': epoch,
      'model': self.state_dict(),
      'optimizer_state_dict': self.optimizer.state_dict(),
      'scheduler': self.scheduler.state_dict(),
      'loss': loss,
      'losses': self.losses,
      }, PATH)
```

When I first start the training it saves in less than 5 seconds. However, after a couple of hours of training it takes over a two minutes to save. The only reason I could think of is the list of losses. But I can't see how that would increase the time by that much.

**Update 1:**
I have my losses as:

```
self.losses = []
```

I'm appending the loss at each epoch to this list as follows:

```
    #... loss calculation
    loss.backward()
    self.optimizer.step()
    self.scheduler.step() 

    self.losses.append(loss)
```

Comment: Can  you show how you append new losses to `self.losses` ? I have a feeling you may store the entire computational graph of each iteration in there, and thus the list could become tremendously big

Comment: Just updated my question. I'm wondering if you're right as my RAM seems to be exploding after a while

Comment: Try `self.losses.append(loss.item())`

Comment: @GoodDeeds Yea! I'm actually in the process of trying that already (just need to wait a bit to see if it works). Looks like commenting out the loss parts (i.e not saving them) solved the issue. I'm wondering why it's saving the entire computational graph when I append it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, the instruction

```
self.losses.append(loss)
```

is definitely the culprit, and shoud be replaced with

```
self.losses.append(loss.item())
```

The reason is that when you store the tensor `loss`, you also store the whole computational graph alongside (all the information that is required to perform the backprop). In other words, you are not merely storing a tensor, but also the pointers to all the tensors that have been involved in the computation of the loss and their relations (which ones were added, multiplied etc). So it will grow really big really fast.

When you do `loss.item()` (or `loss.detach()`, which would work as well), you detach the tensor from the computational graph, and thus you only store what you intended : the loss value itself, as a simple float value

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and answer : )